# Montando dados dinamicos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, mobile

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo hibrido, estou utilizando HTML5 com Java Script, a minha ideia é quando o camarada fazer o login com a conta dele, o aplicativo vai no servidor e busca tudo que é relacionado a aquela pessoa e já monta em uma listview todas as salas daquele camarada.

```
function PesquisaTurma(){
EscreverConsole(console, "Pesquisando turmas");
var read_transition = db.transaction("tbl_TURMAS", "readonly"),
    store = read_transition.objectStore("tbl_TURMAS"),
    rows = store.openCursor(),  
    flag,
    HTMLNovo,
    index,
    $wrapper;
rows.onsuccess = function(evt){
    var cursor = evt.target.result;
    if(cursor)
    { 
    var bd =    db.transaction("tbl_PESSOA_TURMA").objectStore("tbl_PESSOA_TURMA");

        index = bd.index("COD_IDENT_TURMA");
        index.get(cursor.value.COD_IDENT_TURMA).onsuccess = function(event) { 
            $wrapper = document.querySelector('#turma'),

                // Pega a string do conteúdo atual
                var HTMLTemporario = $wrapper.innerHTML;

            flag = event.target.result.FLG_IDENT_PESSO;

            // Novo HTML que será inserido
            HTMLNovo = '<ion-item class="item widget btn_ESCOLHE_TURMA item-avatar" data-uib="ionic/list_item_avatar" data-ver="0">'+'<input id="w_codigo" type="hidden" value="'+cursor.value.COD_IDENT_TURMA+'"/>'+'<img src="images/icon36.png">'+'<h2>'+cursor.value.TXT_NOMEX_TURMA+'</h2>'+ '<p>'+((flag == "M") ? "Você é aluno." : "Você é professor")+'</p>'+'</ion-item>'; 

            HTMLNovo = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;

            // Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
            $wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLNovo;

            //HTMLNovo = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;

            // Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
           $('#turmas').append($wrapper);

        };
        cursor.continue();
    }
}
EscreverConsole(console, "Turmas pesquisadas com sucesso.");    
};
```

Este código funciona legal, porem acontece 2 erros com ele, mais não é de programação.

> 1º Problema - Quando faço login, chamo esta função, porem ele não coloca as turmas imediatamente no aplicativo, é necessário atualizar a pagina para ela aparecer.
>   2º Problema - Se caso faço login duas vezes ele coloca o dobro, e dessa vez ele coloca sem precisar de atualizar a pagina.

Comment: $wrapper.innerHTML aparentemente é o HTMLTemporário, então você não precisa somar com o HTMLNovo e depois atribuir de novo para o $wrapper.innerHTML, compreende ? acho que isso vai resolver seu problema de dobrar.

Comment: Este problema funcionou, porem o outro continua.

Comment: O outro problema não sei exatamente, mas na primeira vez realmente vem alguma coisa no $wrapper.innerHTML ?

Comment: É uma rotina e ela é a seguinte, busco no banco todos os dados, depois rodo uma rotina que salva todo este dados no banco local, após isso faço outro procedimento que busca no banco todas as turmas e monta este listview.

Comment: acredito que após o innerHTML, você vai ter que utilizar o appendChild(), dê uma olhada nesse exemplo: http://jsbin.com/diviyusufe/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Olha como eu fiz:                 HTML.innerHTML = HTMLNovo;
                $wrapper.appendChild(HTML);

Comment: legal @Renan Rodrigues, e funcionou o appendChild ? está incluindo as turmas sem precisar a página ? senão o problema é simplesmente no seletor que não é o correto

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman O problema de atualizar assim que faz o login eu consertei, era porque ele estava fazendo processos antes de outros finalizarem, porem agora ao pegar as turmas so vem a ultima, teria como formular uma resposta para min de como fazer ?

Comment: Atualizei meu código como está agora. A ideia é que preciso que ele pegue 1 e vai adicionando embaixo do outros, se tiver 10 aparece as 10.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29155/discussion-between-thiago-friedman-and-renan-rodrigues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastou eu adicionar um for para que ele carrega-se tudo.
O erro ocorreu pois as turmas estavam na memoria, e quando recarregava ela permanecia apenas uma, fazendo um for, ele carrega todas as turmas de uma so vez.

Segue o código:

```
                for(i=0; i < cursor.length; i++) 
            { 
                // Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
                $('#turmas').append($wrapper);
            }
```